# Is it possible to check the gas fees for a contract before executing the contract itself?

Tags: transactions, gas, uniswap, sushiswap

Is it possible to check the overall gas price of a transaction before executing the contract? I'm trying to implement some arbitrage trade through a smart contract that would find me price discrepancies between sushiswap and uniswap. But I need to check before running the swap if the profit - the gas fees would be in the green, and if it's not, just do not run the transaction. Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a library like **ethers.js** or **web3.js** to estimate the gas usage and cost of the transaction.

A sample code to achieve that using **ethers.js**:

```js
const { ethers } = require('ethers');

const contractAddress = "YOUR_CONTRACT_ADDRESS";

const contractAbi = [
    /* YOUR_CONTRACT_ABI */
];

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("YOUR_RPC_URL");
const privateKey = "YOUR_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY";
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider);

const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, contractAbi, wallet);

contract.estimateGas.yourMethod(params).then(async (gasEstimate) => {

    console.log('Gas Usage Estimate In Wei: ', parseFloat(gasEstimate.toString()));

    const gasEstimateInEther = ethers.utils.formatUnits(gasEstimate);

    console.log('Gas Usage Estimate In Ether: ', gasEstimateInEther);

    const gasData = await wallet.getFeeData();

    const estimatedCostInWei = (gasData.maxFeePerGas.sub(gasData.lastBaseFeePerGas)).mul(gasEstimate);

    console.log('Tx Cost Estimate In Wei: ', parseFloat(estimatedCostInWei.toString()));

    const estimatedCostInEth = ethers.utils.formatUnits(estimatedCostInWei);

    console.log('Tx Cost Estimate In Ether: ', estimatedCostInEth);

    // // Actual call to the contract function
    // contract.yourMethod(params).then((tx) => {
    //     console.log('Tx Hash: ', tx.hash);
    // })

});
```

Comment: So i see where my issue was, I was looking at the v5 version of ethers when I was using the v6 version. The the estimateGas function is now called after the function name.

So the proper way now to call is ```myContract.myContractsFunction.estimateGas```